# How to save click event to HTML form using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, hyperlink

I have an HTML form that includes several links in the following format:

```
<a id="url_1" href="#" target="_blank">LINK</a>
```

How can I detect whether such a link was clicked and then save that event (e.g., as `url_1.clicked`) in my form?

I tried

```
<script>
    function updateInput(){
    document.getElementById("#url_1").value = "clicked";
}
</script>
```

and adding `onclick="updateInput(this.value)"` to the link, but that doesn't work.

I suppose the problem is that the link is not an input and can therefore not be updated. I am stuck however in creating an appropriate input to the form. In the data file that results from submitting the form, one variable should indicate whether the link has been clicked.

Comment: Can you post the whole form and clarify what specifically you want to update when a link is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with the help of a co-worker today. This is the only solution that worked for me:

JavaScript:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
var clickedlinks = [0,0,0,0];

$('html').on('click','.tracked',function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
    console.log(id);
    clickedlinks[id] += 1;
    $('#tracker').val(clickedlinks);
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form>
<a id="url_0" class="tracked" target="_blank">LINK</a>
<a id="url_1" class="tracked" target="_blank">LINK</a>
<a id="url_2" class="tracked" target="_blank">LINK</a>
<a id="url_3" class="tracked" target="_blank">LINK</a>
<input id="tracker" type="hidden" name="tracker">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

The number of times each link was clicked is saved in `clickedlinks` and then sent to the form as `tracker` via a hidden input field. For this to work it is crucial that each link id ends on `_{number}` as in `url_1`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 function updateInput(){
    document.getElementById("url_1").innerHTML = "clicked";
    
}
```

```html
<a id="url_1" href="#" target="_blank" onClick="updateInput()">LINK</a>
```

Adding the onClick to the `<a>` tag is ok for you?

Comment: that will not work, the information of the a-tag is not available when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hidden input to save array of clicked links

```js
var clickedlinks = [];
document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach((a)=>{
 a.addEventListener("click",addtoarr);
});
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit",fnsubmit);

function addtoarr(){
  clickedlinks.push(this.outerHTML);
}

function fnsubmit(){
  this.querySelector("input[type=hidden]").value= JSON.stringify(clickedlinks);
  console.log(JSON.parse(this.querySelector("input[type=hidden]").value)[0]);
  event.preventDefault();//return true;
}
```

```html
<form>
<a id="url_1" href="#" target="_blank">LINK</a>
<input type="hidden" name="clickedlinks">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```js
var ids = ["url_1"];
for(let id of ids) {
  document.querySelector(`a#${id}`).addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("Prevented click navigation on anchor");
    // ...
    // Do your stuff
    // ...
    var link = document.querySelector(`a#${id}`).getAttribute("href");
    if (link[0] == "#") {
      link = `${location.href.split("#")[0]}${link}`;
    }
    location.href = link;
  });
}
```

```html
<a id="url_1" href="#test" target="_blank">LINK</a>
```